# the sound-volume indicator disappeard Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, indicator-sound

I had a problem with sound after I connected a HDMI-cable.
I followed the steps here: http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

the sound worked perfect, but the sound-volume indicator disappeared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try to re-configure it if already installed**

- Open terminal and execute these commands:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | grep indicator-sound | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```
- Logout/restart your system and check whether you get the sound indicator

If above doesn't help then try to re-install `indicator-sound` by executing this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall indicator-sound indicator-sound-gtk2
```

Again logout/restart your system.

Reply if you get any error at any particular command with the error message.