# I've lost access to sound widget after a few updates on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, indicator-sound

I've lost access to sound widget after a few updates on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. I'm attaching a screenshot of my notification bar. Notice that there is no sound icon to adjust sound. The feature has not completely broken, its missing in the bar. I can still access it using settings > sound.

What I have already tried : 
1. restarting Ubuntu system 
2. killing Unity

Please help how to get the sound widget back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone proposed a solution for a similar problem here:
[the sound-volume indicator disappeard Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363354/the-sound-volume-indicator-disappeard-ubuntu-13-10)

To resume, you can check if `indicator-sound` is installed and try to reconfigure it or re-install it.

Comment: I've got this problem corrected.  Basically there is a small tick mark in the sound settings panel that says "show sound in system tray". Due to some update it got unticked (note : canonical must be careful of the updates they are releasing). After I found the problem, I was able to check it again. This effectively solved the problem