# No sound-indicator after login

Tags: 14.04, sound, indicator-sound

Fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install.

I can play sound just fine, but there's no sound indicator. If I go to system settings and then into sound I can make it pop up - but it's in a mute position and I can't change the volume...

The sound devices in the sound settings don't show up and the volume control doesn't work...

However I can set the volume fine on the login screen!

Answer (score 1):

Part-1:

See if the following steps help:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | grep indicator-sound | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot the system.

Still no sound indicator? Then try reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall indicator-sound indicator-sound-gtk2
```

Reboot the system.

Original answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/363369/298860

---

Part-2: (Update)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Then ...

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo reboot
```

If one reboot doesn't do the trick, reboot a couple of times! (No, seriously!)

Comment: Hi, thank you I managed to fix the sound indicator. However the problem remains of the input section in the sound settings being empty. On top of that now I have no sound. If I kilall pulseaudio it comes back, and the input section fills, however the digital output is selected instead of my sound card, and I have to change that for sound to come back :(.

Comment: see if "part-2" in my updated answer solves your problem.

Comment: Doesn't work. Furthermore uninstalling pulse-audio causes these packages to get uninstalled in the process:
  indicator-sound* indicator-sound-gtk2* libcanberra-pulse* pulseaudio*
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-x11* unity-control-center*
  unity-control-center-signon* webaccounts-extension-common*
  xul-ext-webaccounts*

And the indicator disappears completely after that. Need to reinstall ubuntu-base to get it back and all those other packages. Still need to kill pulseaudio after login, before I get the card to show in sound settings and have sound.

Comment: sudo alsa force-reload Indeed fixes it, but just as killing pulseaudio, and without reboot. However it only lasts till I logout, and I have to do it on every login.

Answer (score 1):

There was a dummy user for `speech-dispatcher` that was trying to run the `pulseaudio daemon`, so I had two `pulseaudio-daemons` trying to run at the same time, running this made it so that the audio devices are visible on boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f speech-dispatcher remove
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal either via dash or ctrl+alt+t and paste in the following:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-gtk2
```

Then restart you pc and check your indicators again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When starting my machine I could hear the Ubuntu startup sound. But when logged in there was no sound device to select (and no sound). Apparently I'd thrown out a bit too many dependencies when trying to remove the pulseaudio equalizer.

The line that saved my life was:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base* indicator-sound* libcanberra-pulse* osspd* osspd-pulseaudio* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-x11* unity-control-center* unity-control-center-signon* webaccounts-extension-common* xul-ext-webaccounts*
```